# Netty 4 - in-vm ephemeral channels

Tags: netty

I'm looking to migrate from our current Netty 3.x to the new Netty 4.x, however I don't see an equivalent to the 3.x's (org.jboss.netty.channel.local.LocalAddress) ephemeral addresses.  There is an equivalent class in the new package structure however it looks like it is used for a different purpose, not to mention a package-private constructor.

Does anyone know how I can migrate 3.x ephemeral address to 4.x?  There doesn't seem to be anything in the migration documentation either. http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy.html

Client connection:

```
    int port = 10000;
    ClientBootstrap clientBootstrap = new ClientBootstrap();
    clientBootstrap.connect(new LocalAddress(port));
```

Server connection:

```
    int port = 10000;
    ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    serverBootstrap.bind(new LocalAddress(port));
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me the code you want to "migrate" ? It should be all in the io.netty.channel.local package

Comment: Apologies, have updated the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies.  I didn't realise that the LocalAddress constructor had changed from a LocalAddress(int) to LocalAddress(String).  So in Netty 4.x it is now

```
int port = 10000;
ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
serverBootstrap.bind(new LocalAddress(Integer.toString(port)));
```